# Can't run Makefile.am, what should I do?

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, autotools

I got a C project to compile and run in Linux. It is a very big project with many subdirectories.  Inside the parent directory there are files `Makefile.am` and `Makefile.in`.

I tried running `make -f Makefile.am`, and got the following error:

```
make: Nothing to be done for `Makefile.am'.
```

What does it mean?  How do I accomplish my task?

Answer (score 26):

These files are used with the [Autotools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_build_system) suite. Makefile.am files are compiled to Makefiles using [automake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automake).

Have a look to see if there is a `configure` script in the directory. If there is, then type:

```
./configure
```

If not, then run:

```
autoreconf
```

in the directory, which should create the `configure` script (you will need to have the Autotools suite installed to run this).

After that, you should have a `configure` script that you can run.

After the configure is complete, you should have a normal Makefile in the directory, and will be able to run

```
make
```

Comment: As I said, you will need to have the Autotools suite installed to run that command. Have a look here: http://sourceware.org/autobook/autobook/autobook_274.html

Comment: i installed. now it says that it needs configure.in or configure.ac

Comment: Well it seems that perhaps all of the 'developer' parts of the source are not there. Are you sure there isn't a `configure` file in the directory? (If there is but it just not executable, you can always run it with `sh configure`)

Comment: Also, you could try running `autoscan` to see if that creates you a usable `configure.in` file. My guess is that you may have to edit it though to make it usable.

Comment: `autoreconf` can be installed with `sudo apt install autoconf`

Answer (score 14):

What has been left out:

- Makefile.am are transformed to Makefile.in using automake.
- Makefile.in are transformed to Makefile by running configure.

Neither of these (Makefile.{am,in}) are supposed to be used with `make -f`.

If the tarball already ships with configure, just run that and make. If it does not, run `./autogen.sh` or `bootstrap`(*). If that does not exist, use `autoreconf` instead.

(*) autogen/bootstrap: A convenience script added by developers that *should* just call `autoreconf`. Unfortunately there are some people that eschew autoreconf and unnecessarily call all the lowlevel commands themselves.

Answer (score 3):

To supplement what has already been said:
Search for a script called *configure* in the project directory. If it is there, building the project will be:

./configure

make

and optionally, to install:

sudo make install

or su -c "make install"

Even if there is no *configure* script. there might be one *autogen.sh*. Run this script to generate the configure script and do as above.

Answer (score 1):

`Makefile.am` is probably to be used with [automake](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/).

try:

```
automake
```

you might also just want to try

```
make -f Makefile.in
```

Since this is the product of running automake

Comment: configure.in or configure.ac are required