# libao: os_types.h.in not converted to os_types.h by autoreconf

Tags: c++, audio, header-files, autoconf, autoreconf

I am using [libao](https://gitlab.xiph.org/xiph/libao) in my C++ code. To set up the build system, I run the `autogen.sh` script (which uses `autoreconf`) in the repo. It works, but the `os_types.h.in` in `include/ao/` doesn't get converted to `os_types.h`.

`os_types.h` is needed because when I try to include `#include <libao/include/ao/ao.h>`  the compiler says that it `cannot open source file "os_types.h" (dependency of "libao/include/ao/ao.h")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that I needed to run `./configure` and then `make` and I had the os_types.h file. Answer found from: [Can't run Makefile.am, what should I do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203208/cant-run-makefile-am-what-should-i-do)